# How to load a dynamic form in Modal in angular 7 where the formcontrols (input fields ) also loaded from api call

Tags: asynchronous, bootstrap-modal, angular7, httpclient, formgroups

The problem is that the input fields to be put in as formcontrols are got from API back end call as it keeps changing. The form keeps throwing error "cannot find control name".By the time the http call returns (using subscribe), the form is delivered on the screen and I am unable to create formcontrols on time.. Thus throwing the error..
Has anyone done such scenario?

Comment: you want to create forms dynamically, right?

Comment: Yes. I have managed to create the form dynamically.. But now, i have another problem. The API response gives me nested json fields.. and am not able to patch those values into form control.

Answer (score 0):

You can create forms dynamically from your response. - >

```
for (item of response.items) {
    const formGroup = {
        form: this.formBuilder.group({
            fromVal: ['', Validators.required],
            toVal: ['', Validators.required],
            }),
        };
    this.fromArray.push(formGroup);
}
```

Then you can access them in your view - >

```
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let riskClass; let i = index;" class="px-0 col">
        <form [formGroup]="fromArray[i].form" >
           <label class="no-wrap mr-3">FROM : </label>
        <input formControlName="fromVal"
            [value]="fromArray[i].form.get('fromVal').value"
            class="form-control no-radius mt-0 mr-3"/>
       </form>
   </mat-cell>
```

Comment: Thanks Asel.. do u know how to patch vaules to formcontrols when the fiels are nested?

Comment: {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "orange",
    "description": "",
    "details": {
        "cost": "",
        "expiry": ""}  Response comes like this. and am not able to set the values of fieds like cost, expiry into the form. I am trying with patchvalues.